# Definition of fractional in theoretical CS

Tags: graph-algorithms, online-algorithms

What is the definition of the word "fractional" in algorithms? I have encountered the word in phrases like "fractional algorithm", "fractional node routing problem".

Note: English is not my native language

Comment: I have also encountered the phrase "[...]designing a fractional algorithm and transforming it into a discrete algorithm [...]". Could the word "fractional" mean "continuous"?

Comment: Suresh's answer is correct. See Chapter 11 of Vazirani's Approximation algorithms book for an example of such algorithms. The book is available at https://www.ceid.upatras.gr/webpages/courses/approx/book.pdf

Comment: there is also a sense of "fractional" wrt graphs referring to hypergraphs. use of the term presumably is broad and does not have a fully general crosscutting concept or definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common use of 'fractional' is when you're solving an integer program. You relax it by dropping the constraints that the solution be integers, thus yielding a **linear** program in which the variables can take **fractional** values (fractional comes from fraction). Later, you can convert the fractional values into integers via a process called 'rounding'.